# Function not working correctly in python script

Tags: python

Question I want to compare a full name with the persons initials but, for some reason I keep getting this error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
#check.py", line 27, in check_fn a = self.my_name AttributeError: 'Check' object has no attribute 'my_name'
```

```
  import re 
  class Check(object): 


    def __init__(self, word): 
       self.word = word 

    def abbr(self): 
       e = self.word 
       w = self.word[:1] 
       lens = len(self.word) 
       last = self.word[-1:] 
       all = '%s%s%s' %(w, lens, last) 

       key_a = [] 
       key_b = [] 

       app_a = key_a.append(e) 
       app_b = key_b.append(all) 

       dictonary = dict(zip(key_a, key_b)) 
       self.check_fn(e, all) 
       return dictonary 


    def check_fn(self, my_name, intials): 
      a = self.my_name 
      b = self.intials 

      list_a = [] 
      list_b = [] 

      aa = list_a.append(a) 
      bb = list_b.append(b) 

      for element in list_a: 
        m = re.match("(^['%s' %(list_b)]\d)", element) 
        if m: 
          print(m.groups())
```

Comment: in check_fn method, you are affecting self.my_name to "a", but my_name is not an attribute of check class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've never defined `self.my_name` (or `self.intials` for that matter).

your code:

```
  a = self.my_name 
  b = self.intials
```

did you want to have this code?

```
  a = my_name 
  b = intials
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer what I want to do is pass the two variables in my check_fn function. so basically take e variable which is self.word then take all variable which is the initial and then pass it into my check_fn to see if any letters match. @DomTomCat

Answer (score 1):

'self' points to the object of same class. Here my_name and initials are not defined in the class 'check'.

```
a = my_name 
b = intials
```

As these parameters are passed through the function, the above snippet will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's raising AttributeError because in the you haven't declared self.my_name or self.initials therefore your Check class hasn't got an attribute called my_name.